# "numeric" error in R

Tags: r

I have a big dataset in `txt` format separated by one space, which I read in `R`. The dataset has numbers with 8 or 9 decimal points.  when I want to do basic stat analysis, I get this error:

```
 Error in hist.default(GR, prob = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
```

This is how I've written it:

```
 Data = as.matrix(read.table("C:/MyData/Data.txt"),header=TRUE );

 GR=Data[,14];

 hist(GR, prob=TRUE);
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's possible that you have missing values or string values in your data. Check `class(GR)` to determine the class of your data. I suppose it will be "factor".

Comment: yes, looks like you read it in as text. did you probably misspecify the decimal sign or something like this? try `str(Data)` probably

Comment: It would also help if you make a snippet (maybe the first ten rows) of the data file available.

Comment: Does `Data <- as.matrix(read.table("C:/MyData/Data.txt"), header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)` help?

Comment: Also, end of line semicolons are superfluous in R. Your code will look cleaner without them.

Comment: Thanks guys for your helpful comments. I used class(GR) and type of my data was character. So I used  GR=sapply(Data[2:m,14], as.numeric) and converted that to numeric. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

I think your biggest problem is some misplaced parentheses -- your command should probably read

```
as.matrix(read.table("C:/MyData/Data.txt",header=TRUE ))
```

because `header=TRUE` is an argument to `read.table`, not to `as.matrix` (where it is silently ignored).  The fix-up you describe above (using `as.numeric` to convert) will work, but will leave you with a row of `NA` values at the top of your data set where the header names were, and will leave you without meaningful column names -- either of which could be a problem somewhere down the road.